# Sigma.js - displaying edge labels and using external json file

Tags: javascript, json, sigma.js

I am having trouble building a sigma.js graph with edge labels, with the input for the graph using an external JSON file. 
Here is the js code:

```
<script>
sigma.parsers.json('/project/data/graph.json', {
  container: 'graph-container',
  renderer: {
    container: document.getElementById('graph-container'),
    type: 'canvas'
  },
  settings: {
    edgeLabelSize: 'proportional'
  }
}
</script>
```

The error generated on chrome comes from the penultimate '}' and says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token /". Below is an example of my JSON file:

```
    "nodes": [
        {
            "id":"1",
            "label":"Station 1",
            "x" : "0",
            "y" : "0",
            "size" : "10"
        },
        {
            "id":"2",
            "label":"Station 2",
            "x" : "6",
            "y" : "3",
            "size" : "10" 
        } ],
    "edges": [
        {
            "id" : "1",
            "source" : "1",
            "target" : "2",
            "label" : "Rail 1"
        } ]
```

I'm pretty new to js so it's hopefully something simple, still any assistance is much appreciated! :)

Comment: Are you sure `edgeLabelSize` is a valid setting? It's not listed in the sigma.js [wiki](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/wiki/Settings) (which, AFAICT, is the closest thing to an official API for the library).

Comment: Hi @StephenThomas, edgeLabelSize was a setting I obtained from this  [example](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/examples/edge-renderers.html) on the github repository.

Answer (score 0):

The error was thrown as some of my full JSON code has comments in it which isn't supported by JSON. However, after this another error came up saying "Container not found". This was caused by having 2 container lines in the code below:

```
 sigma.parsers.json('/project/data/graph.json', {
    container: 'graph-container',
    renderer: {
      container: document.getElementById('graph-container'),
      type: 'canvas'
    },
```

I edited this code to:

```
 sigma.parsers.json('/project/data/graph.json', {
       renderer: {
        container: 'graph-container',
        type: 'canvas'
       },
```

And it works as expected. Credit to Yomguithereal for helping me out over on Github. Full issue details can be found [here](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/issues/533#issuecomment-86936883).